# Test instance variable is assigned

Tags: rspec, shoulda

I liked using this to test the correct instance variable was set:

```
it { should assign_to(:resource) }
```

I can't find it any more https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers.

How can I get it back or write my own matcher?

Why did they remove it? Seems useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick matcher I threw together in a few minutes:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :set_the_instance_variable do |instance| 
    match do |actual|
        @actual = controller.instance_variable_get(instance)
        @actual == @value
    end

    failure_message_for_should do |actual|
        "Expected '#{instance}' to equal #{@value}. However, it did not: \n '#{@actual.inspect}' \n '#{@value.inspect}'"
    end

    failure_message_for_should_not do |actual|
        "Expected '#{instance}' to not equal #{@value}. However, it did: \n '#{@actual.inspect}' \n '#{@value.inspect}'"        end

    description do
        "'#{instance}' should equal #{@value}."
    end

    def to(value)
        @value = value
        self
    end
end
```

Usage

```
it { should set_the_instance_variable(:@folder).to(parent_folder)}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this variable is not from your public interface there is no point in testing it. If you have an accesor for it you could use `respond_to` combined with `eq` to check the value is correctly set.